# Basic real analysis - Root test (question on example from book)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Just a quick question. I can't seem to see through the math or follow through with this example from the textbook. I don't see the connection or the jump where it says it concludes the limit is 1/2. It is the underlined part in the image.

[Example from book, "Elementary Analysis, The Theory of Calculus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HA3mD.png)

Comment: Could you provide us with theorem 9.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $2^{-1/n - 1} = {1\over2} 2^{-1/n}$ and $2^{1/n - 1} = {1\over2} 2^{1/n}$, giving you this limit.

Answer (score 1):

Note

$$ (a_n)^{1/n} =  2^{ \frac{1}{n} - 1} = \frac{ 2^{\frac{1}{n}} }{2} $$

and

$$ 2^{ -\frac{1}{n} - 1} = \frac{ 2^{-\frac{1}{n}} }{2} $$